# How do I set up an SSH key for some user, if I'm root?

Tags: linux, git, bash, ssh

If a root user is running a bash script that configure some stuff on machine for a user. The script would configure a git repository and an ssh key for password-less github communication, then it would clone the repository.
This will only happens once.

I'm new to bash, how would I do this?

My solution so far (this script is run as root):

```
USERNAME="vagrant"
HOMEDIR="/home/$USERNAME"

apt-get update -y
apt-get install git -y
cp id_rsa* $HOMEDIR/.ssh #copying predefined keys
su -c "eval `ssh-agent -s` ssh-add $HOMEDIR/.ssh/id_rsa" $USERNAME
chmod 400 $HOMEDIR/.ssh/id_rsa
cat $HOMEDIR/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > $HOMEDIR/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This doesn't work because the key is not being added, I get the error:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Comment: Why has the script to be run as a root user?

Comment: This is a good resource - https://github.com/saga-project/BigJob/wiki/Configuration-of-SSH-for-Password-less-Authentication

Comment: the `su -c` line is completely pointless as `id_rsa` is one of the files that is automatically searched for when performing an ssh invocation. I'd do a chown on the id_rsa file to make sure that it's owned by the user in question. I'm not endorsing this process *at all*

Comment: @akluth Even if I run the script with sudo (as it needs to install some packages beforehand) it will still won't work.

Comment: Are you using vagrant? If so and you're working on a box which was set up with the known conventions the vagrant user has password-less sudo rights. Consider using Puppet or Chef to do the setup as above described (and of course if you're using vagrant).

Answer (score 0):

With a root user that has no login on a remote host, and `/root/.ssh` does not exist, I can interactively ssh in with:

```
su - $USERNAME -c "ssh $USERNAME@<remotehost>"
```

It reads USERNAME's `~/.ssh/known_hosts file` (or prompts for verification). If correct keys exist in USERNAME's `~/.ssh` it uses them. When done, there is still no `/root/.ssh`, i.e. this is completely done as USERNAME, not root.

Likewise with git cloning:

```
su - $USERNAME -c "git clone remoteuser@host:/path/to/repo"
```

Just be careful of quoting. If you want a variable dereferenced at the time you run `su`, use double quotes. If you want a variable dereferenced after `su` has handed off to the user's shell, use single quotes. Example:

```
su - myuser -c "echo $HOME"
/root

su - myuser -c 'echo $HOME'
/home/myuser
```